# pygame drawing polygons issue, 1 player vs 100 players

Tags: python, pygame

So I have an issue with pygame not drawing polygons of Player objects.

When I have a single Player such as p = Player(...), or players.append(Player(...)) only once. will draw the player fine. But when I try to have 2 or more Players in a list none draw on the screen. I know that the way they are set up right now they are all overlapped, and thus would look like there is only 1 Player, but I am seeing none:

lib/Player.py

```
class player:
    center_pos = [0, 0]
    points = [[-3, 3], [3, 3], [0, -10]]
    screen = pygame = color = None

    def __init__(self, start, screen, pygame, color):
        self.center_pos = start

        self.points[0] = [self.points[0][0] + start[0], self.points[0][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[1] = [self.points[1][0] + start[0], self.points[1][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[2] = [self.points[2][0] + start[0], self.points[2][1] + start[1]]

        self.screen = screen
        self.pygame = pygame
        self.color = color

    def update(self):
        self.pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, self.color, self.points, 0)
```

main.py

```
import sys, pygame, math

pygame.init()

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))

from lib.Player import Player

players = []

for i in range(0, 100):
    players.append(Player([width/2, height-24], screen, pygame, BLUE))

while 1:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for player in players:
        player.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Where are you swapping the display buffers?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy making sure to copy the chunk giving me problems I forgot to include the normal stuff. I updated the question

Comment: that's interesting, can definitely replicate it

Comment: ah found the issue i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a class, all variables not `self.` are shared be all instantiations... *including* `points` (which you increment for each class, hence you'll see it working for if there's up to 8 or so objects drawn, they just gradually move (depending on your width and height values, I used 100 for each).

```
class player:
    center_pos = [0, 0] # Shared!
    points = [[-3, 3], [3, 3], [0, -10]] # Shared!
    screen = pygame = color = None

    def __init__(self, start, screen, pygame, color):
        self.center_pos = start

        self.points[0] = [self.points[0][0] + start[0], self.points[0][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[1] = [self.points[1][0] + start[0], self.points[1][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[2] = [self.points[2][0] + start[0], self.points[2][1] + start[1]]
        ...
```

Try this:

```
class player:
    screen = pygame = None

    def __init__(self, start, screen, pygame, color):
        self.center_pos = start
        self.points = [[-3, 3], [3, 3], [0, -10]]

        self.points[0] = [self.points[0][0] + start[0], self.points[0][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[1] = [self.points[1][0] + start[0], self.points[1][1] + start[1]]
        self.points[2] = [self.points[2][0] + start[0], self.points[2][1] + start[1]]

        self.screen = screen
        self.pygame = pygame
        self.color = color

    def update(self):
        self.pygame.draw.polygon(self.screen, self.color, self.points, 0)
```

Comment: @Drew, don't forget to remove `color` as well! That would be shared too

Comment: That fixed this issue. Its good to know that anything not `self` is shared in a class. Been a while since I have done anything with python. Thanks.

Comment: @Drew I'm not certain that's true, it just appears to be that in this case, just remember that anything `self` is specific to that object, if you want something to be for only one object, only use `self.varname` for that variable